# transfer a file from one domain to another via wp

Tags: plugins, uploads, ftp

I want to be able to transfer a file from one domain to another via wp.

I have searched Google and this site but only found info on how to transfer entire WP sites.

I was hoping to find a plugin that allows me to enter the URL of a file and WP transfer the file into the media folder.

For example:

Enter file location: [http:/ /myothersite.com/downloads/newfile.zip]

Then, the file would be deposited directly into http:/ /mywpsite.com/media/2016/03/20/newfile.zip

(Obviously, fake urls here)

Comment: Plugin requests are off topic. And, why exactly do you want to transfer files that way? Other than use FTP?

Comment: I apologize if this is off-topic.  My need is to transfer files without downloading them first. 

I often work on sites from remote locations with my iPad or a laptop tethered to it.  The iPad works slowly upload or download.

Even from my home, we have 30MBPS+ download speed, but less than 1MBPS upload.  I feel like I am on a dial up modem when I upload.

I can use cPanel to transfer files within my host server, but since I have two servers and some files are edited or compiled on 3rd party servers, I need to be able to transfer the files, especially when operating on a remote mountain top.

Comment: Use scp over SSH http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/scp.1?query=scp&sec=1

Comment: The link you sent appears to be server side linux commands.  WP is hosted on remote sites such as BlueHost and Hostgator.  How would I implement this command in WP?

Rereading my comment, I see I said "since I have two servers" which is misleading. I don't have WP servers, I use host servers such as Hostgator and some sites I support are on additional host services such as bluehost, etc.  My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use WordPress to move files between servers is like trying to use a car to mow the yard. It doesn't work because they are the wrong tools. It can work, with a lot of custom code, but why bother? You're going about it backwards.

If you read about SSH and SCP, you will see that you can move files *directly* between hosts without downloading them to your own iPad. That's what you need to do. SSH to one host, use SCP from that shell and move the files from one host to the other.

You could write some sort of plugin that lets you use SSH from within the WordPress application layer, but again: why bother? Use SSH directly.

Bluehost commonly allows SSH access with some of their accounts; I don't know about Hostgator.